# how to get dynamic array value in a nested onclick method (android)?

Tags: java, android, arrays, onclicklistener

I have an array of text views called plans and an array of integers called months, the text views are clickable and I want to take the value of one of the months' values inside OnClick Listener method but it shows either an error (when I initialize the months with a variable) or always zero (when I initialize the months with fixed size)

```
package //...
Import //...
public class saving_consultation extends AppCompatActivity {

   private TextView[] plans;
   private TextView firstplan;
   private TextView altplan1;
   private TextView altplan2;
   private TextView altplan3;

   int[] months; // months of all plans
   int month; // used to select a month
   private int N; // total number of plans and months
   private int i;

   // rest of the variables

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      firstplan = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.first_plan);
      altplan1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.plan1);
      altplan2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.plan2);
      altplan3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.plan3);

      N = 4;
      months = new int[N];
      plans = new TextView[N];

      plans[0] = firstplan;
      plans[1] = altplan1;
      plans[2] = altplan2;
      plans[3] = altplan3;

      // some code

      somebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         // some code

         for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            plans[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                  new AlertDialog.Builder(saving_consultation.this)
                     .setTitle("title")
                     .setMessage("msg")
                     .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                           try {

                              month = months[i];

                              // other code that adds to a database, works perfectly fine without using the month array

                             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SUCCESS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                          } catch (Exception e) {
                             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                          } // End catch
                    }}) // End yes dialog 
                    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null).show();
           }}); // End plans OnClick()
        } // End for loop

     }}); // End outter OnClick()
   } // End OnCreat()
} // End class
```

I tried to put`month = months[i]` after the for loop directly but it always takes the last index, I don't know how to fix this

Comment: where are you initializing the `months` array?

Comment: @Twista In `onCreat()`

Comment: I actually meant populating the values.Because after initializing an integral array, the elements by default are zeros. It is expected that `months[i]` will be a zero for all values of `i`

Comment: @Twista I do some calculations and then I add it, I know it's not zeros because it shows in the interface before the `plan[i].onClick`. as I mentioned, if I put `month = months[i]` right after the for loop it takes the last index's value, but it's the last on every click